# Правильная проверка обычной переменной на вхождение в enum.

Tags: c++, enum, c++14

Доброго времени суток. Ситуация следующая, с сервера приходит пакет, в определённом поле которого есть байт, который я хочу передавать в метод как член определённого enum’а. Для приведения я использую статик каст, но я задумался о том, что будет, если сервер пришлёт мне некорректные данные и значение в этом байте окажется за пределами enum’а. Накидал тестовый код и как оказалось С++ спокойно это проглотит и не чего не бросит (.

```
enum class MyEnum {
    Red = 1,
    Black = 2,
    White = 3
};
void Foo(MyEnum val) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(val) << std::endl;
};

int main()
{
    Foo(MyEnum::Red);
    Foo(static_cast<MyEnum>(3));
    Foo(static_cast<MyEnum>(5));
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Есть ли какие-то стандартные средства эффективно (с точки зрения производительности) проверить вхождение значения в конкретный enum и дать мне возможность бросит исключение. Если их нет, то как это сделать, не перелопачивая весь enum руками. И можно ли как то сделать foreach обход enuma не городя огород (что то типа for (auto i : MyEnum) ...)?

p.s. С++ 14 компилятор GCC 6.3.

Comment: switch с default с точки зрения быстродействия будет "мгновенный", тут нечего беспокоится, но с точки зрения написания для нескольких enum`ов со множеством значений увы и ах.

Comment: Не предназначены enum-ы для такой цели.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я тут для вас кое что сооброзил, не знаю насколько поможет. Вам придется просто после добавления в перечислении, добавлять и в оператор ++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
enum class Some
{
    min,
    s1 = 3,
    s2 = 5,
    s3 = 7,
    max = 9,
    end = 100
};
Some& operator++(Some& s)
{
    switch(s)
    {
    case Some::min:     return s = Some::s1;
    case Some::s1:      return s = Some::s2;
    case Some::s2:      return s = Some::s3;
    case Some::s3:      return s = Some::max;
    case Some::max:     s = Some::end;
    }
   return  s;
}

int main()
{    
    int n = 5, index;
    Some t = Some::min;
    while (int(t) != n  && t != Some::end) {
        ++t;
        ++index;
    }
     if (t == Some::end)
         cout << "indefined" ;
     else
         cout << index; // выдаст 2

    return 0;
}
```

Ну можно это все проделать в какой то функции, или на основе этого создавать класс - итератор. Тут index  будет иметь значение как индекс в векторах...

Comment: Большое спасибо. Но у вас добавление нового члена enum должно сопровождается добавлением нового члена за его пределами (я про это писал в другом ответе). У меня такого точно быть не должно. Через три месяца добавляя новый член в enum я обязательно забуду добавить его в функцию перегрузки даже если напишу про это капсом в коментах. А другие люди, работающие с моим классом, не скажут мне спасибо. Когда нужно поменять какой-то параметр системы то у меня он должен меняться в одном, единственном месте. Если это не так, то у меня всегда начинаются большие проблемы и выливается многочасовую отладку.

Comment: @mrFieldy, через 3 месяца  ваше перечисление должно где то хранится в программе, там и храните оператор.  Храните их в каком то пространстве имен, тогда не забудете.  Других решений в голову не пришло

Answer (score 3):

Enum-типы в С++ гарантируют представимость любых целочисленных значений в диапазоне от `0` до `2^n`, где `n` - минимальное количество битов необходимое для представления явно объявленных членов enum. (Строгая формулировка более сложна, но идея именно такая.) Нет ничего нелегального в записи в enum-объекты значений из этого диапазона при помощи явного приведения типа, даже если записываемое значение не совпадает ни с одним из поименованных.

Средств перечисления элементов enum в языке нет. Да и не может их быть, ибо никто не гарантировал однозначного соответствия элементов enum целочисленным значениям. Можно хоть всем им назначить одно и то же значение

```
enum class MyEnum {
    Red = 1,
    Black = 1,
    White = 1
};
```

Ничего нелегального в этом нет.

Другими словами enum-тип покрывает целый диапазон целочисленных значений, и лишь некоторые из значений этого диапазона поименованы (возможно многократно). Проверить значение на поименованность можно только вручную, т.е. в простейшем случае прямым сравнением с именованными значениями.

Comment: Но вопрос в другом. Я понимаю, что это очень гибко, но мне нужно написать безопасное приложение. Когда мне приходит значение которого нет в enum мне нужно бросить исключение. Как мне это лучше сделать? Задача, как мне кажется, довольно типичная.

Comment: @mrFieldy, именно что "кажется" :)

Comment: @mrFieldy, вы же вручную придаете имена битам, вам и придется вручную проверять. Другой вопрос где и как вы это сделаете

Comment: @ARHovsepyan почему у вас ручное добавление тождественно ручной проверке или обходу? В C# допустим я бы легко это реализовал. Меня удивляет почему в С++ и в std такой бедный функционал по работе с enum'ами. Почему в std нельзя было реализовать какой ни будь функции создания итератора по enum (я понимаю, что enum это тип).

Comment: @ mrFieldy, я не оттметил, что это была шутка - иногда шутить тоже полезно... Но ваш вопрос я отмечу как полезный, поскольку он меня заинтриговал  подумать над этим. В жизни почти нет невозможного, есть только те, у кого это не получается, а С++  язык  "жизненный".

Comment: @mrFieldy, по поводу std  библиотеки :  ее не станут засорять  функциями и классами разного рода индивидуальными решениями, которым пользоваться будут редкие люди.  Она должна давать лишь только инструменты мастерам, которые  выполняют конкретную функцию...

Comment: Почему от `0`, а как же отрицательные значения?

Comment: Если приходит байт, то и работайте с ним. Сделайте карту разрешенных значений и проверяйте. Зачем лишнее то городить?

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>

enum class MyEnum {
    Unknown = 0,
    Red = 1,
    Black = 2,
    White = 3,

    // новые значения вписывать сюда

    Max
};
void Foo(MyEnum val) {
    std::cout << static_cast<int>(val) << std::endl;
}

bool checkEnum(MyEnum _val)
{
    return _val > MyEnum::Unknown && _val < MyEnum::Max;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << checkEnum(MyEnum::Red) << std::endl;
    std::cout << checkEnum(static_cast<MyEnum>(3)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << checkEnum(static_cast<MyEnum>(5)) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод будет:

```
true true false
```

Правда тут одно ограничение, Red, Black, White - должны быть значениями по порядку, нельзя писать:

```
enum class MyEnum {
    Unknown = 0,
    Red = 1,
    Black = 3,
    White = 6,

    // новые значения вписывать сюда

    Max
};
```

Если же значения не идут по порядку, то возможен такой вариант, правда тут после добавления значения в enum, нужно добавить значение и в set

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

enum class MyEnum {
    Red = 1,
    Black = 3,
    White = 6,
};

static std::set<MyEnum> enumArr{
    MyEnum::Red,
    MyEnum::Black,
    MyEnum::White
};

bool checkEnum(MyEnum _val)
{
    return enumArr.find(_val) != enumArr.end();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout
            << std::boolalpha
            << checkEnum(MyEnum::Red) << " "
            << checkEnum(static_cast<MyEnum>(3)) << " "
            << checkEnum(static_cast<MyEnum>(5));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: К сожалению значения не могут идти по порядку, и этот enum будет всё время расширятся. Но большое спасибо за идею, как это сделать с постоянными enum'ами.

Comment: @mrFieldy, Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Про эти огороды я и говорю. Очень бы не хотелось их городить. Все эти изменения должны происходить в одном месте и распространятся на весь код. Я вам гарантирую что через 3 месяца добавляя новые значения в enum я обязательно забуду добавить значение в set. Но если другого выхода нет, то придётся городить что-то подобное.

Comment: @mrFieldy, enum'ы не предназначены для того, что вы хотите с ними делать, потому придется городить огороды какие-то, скорее всего с использованием макросов. Хотя если бы у Вас был Qt, то его Q_ENUM скорее всего решил бы Ваши проблемы.